# Authenticate user using Microsoft Account in .Net backend Azure Mobile service giving error after login

Tags: c#, azure, windows-store-apps, uwp, azure-mobile-services

I am developing Windows 10 UWP app in that I am Implementing authenticate user using Azure Mobile Services using Microsoft account as provider.

I followed the below article for registering mobile service with the app

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-register-microsoft-authentication/

The following are the details I updated in my app live settings
[image]

My Mobile service is a .net backend service https://astraniprod.azure-mobile.net/

And also updated the client ID, secret, app SID in Mobile Service.

After that I have written the below code to launch the login popup in my app

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> AuthenticateAsync()
    {
        string message;
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            // Change 'MobileService' to the name of your MobileServiceClient instance.
            // Sign-in using Facebook authentication.
            user = await App.MobileService
                .LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount,true);
            message =
                string.Format("You are now signed in - {0}", user.UserId);

            success = true;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            message = "You must log in. Login Required";
        }

        var dialog = new MessageDialog(message);
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK"));
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
        return success;
    }
}
```

I am able to see the login dialogue and also entered my Microsoft account and password, After that I am getting the following error

[image]

I seen other people also posted about this in forums but I didn't find the solution for the issue, I don't know where the issue is, other Providers like Google, Twitter, Facebook working fine, but only Microsoft account not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with the redirect URI.

If you open a browser to 
http://astraniprod.azure-mobile.net/login/microsoftaccount

You should get a login page, login, and you'll get the "unable to complete your request" page.

In the URL is a parameter, which indicates the issue:
error_description=The+provided+value+for+the+input+parameter+'redirect_uri'+is+not+valid.+The+expected+value+is+'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf'+or+a+URL+which+matches+the+redirect+URI+registered+for+this+client+application.

Can you make sure your app is configured to watch for a redirect to https://astraniprod.azure-mobile.net/signin-microsoft

Also, make sure you associated your app with the store as per step 2, 3, 4:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-register-microsoft-authentication/

If you've done the above, it should work.  If not, we'll help look further.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and valuable explanation, It is working now I mistakenly added space at the end of the URL that's caused this issue.